# What's the use of the general solution when solving an inhomogeneous ODE using variation of parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When solving a (first order) linear ODE using variation of parameters, the final solution is $y_g+y_p$, where $y_g$ is a solution to the homogeneous equation, and $y_p$ is a particular solution to the equation.

So why do we bother added $y_g$ to the final solution? To me that seems similar to saying that the solution to $4+5=9+0$, what's the use of adding the $0$?

Thanks

Edit: an example to illustrate my confusion

The equation

$$y'+xy=xe^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$$

Has as a general solution $y_g=ce^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$. So than to find the particular solution:

$C'(x)e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}=xe^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$

$C(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2+c$

So the particular solution is $y_p=(\frac{1}{2}x^2+c)e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$. And from here we can already solve initial value problems, there really is no point in added the general solution to this...

Comment: your $y_g$ only satisfies the homogenous equation $y' + xy = 0$ not the forced equation $y' + xy = xe^{-1/2 x^2}$

Comment: @abel Yea but that's the idea of the general solution right? It's the solution to the homogeneous equation.

Comment: not at all. general solution means it satisfies the differential equation and has enough number of parameters to satisfy any initial conditions.

Comment: @abel Oke so this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#First_order_equation is wrong then?

Comment: does wikipedia say otherwise?

Comment: @abel It says: "Solve the corresponding homogeneous equation to find the general solution: $y'=p(x)y=0 $...[skipping some stuff].... The general equation is therefore $y_g=Ce^{-\int{p(x)dx}}$"

Comment: do you see that the particular solution you have $y_p = 1/2x^2e^{-1/2x^2}$ satisfies the differential equation and the initial condition $y = 0$ at $x = 0$ it cannot satisfy any other initial condition. you need the $ce^{-x^2/2}$ for that.

Comment: @abel That is not my particular solution though, my particular solution contains a constant $c$ so it can satisfy other initial values

Comment: i think you are using the term particular solution in a different way than i am using. the solution with the right hand side zero is called the homogeneous solution. any general solution is also a particular solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20989/discussion-between-user2520938-and-abel).

Answer (score 1):

When you solve an ODE by Variation of Parameters you will have a solution $y_p$. Adding the homogenous solution $y_g$ you will simply add a constant to the variated Parameter. The general solution is important to fit the solution of your ODE to your initial condition (then, the constants involved by homogenous solution can be determined).

Comment: Can you take a look at my edit and tell me what you think of it?

Comment: In your example the particular solution would be $y_p=\frac{x^2}{2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ (particular Solutions are Chosen such that there are no Integration constants contained) while your homogenous solution is $ce^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$. Adding both together you have the General solution.

Comment: Oke say why are particular solutions chosen such that there are no integration constants contained? That seems quite arbitrary

Comment: all Integration constants are contained in the homogenous solution. First you find the homogenous solution and then; from the homogenous solution you add a particular solution that solves the whole ODE; there is no necessity anymore to define more Integration constants.

Comment: Hm well oke. I get that it's not needed to introduce more constants, but since I just introduce the constants into the particular solution and than forget about the homogeneous one, the end result will be the same regardless. Anyway thanks for your time and explaination

Answer (score 0):

we add $y_g$ to the particular solution so that $y$ can satisfy the initial condition. remember that any general solution is also a particular solution and that we don't care about the initial conditions when finding a particular solution.

Comment: Can you take a look at my edit and tell me what you think of it?